# how can use url image to notification LargeIcon in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

how can use url image to notification LargeIcon in Android?

I use this way, but the largeIcon cannot display.

```
 Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
bigPhoto = data.get("photo").toString();

            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), fid,bigPhoto);

 private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody, String fid,String bigPhoto) {

Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bigPhoto);
        Log.d("DDD", bigPhoto);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.luvtas_au3)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setGroup(channelId)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
         notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

I can get the image URL, but it's not shown to the notification.

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/itinerary.colatour.com.tw/COLA_AppFiles/A03A_Tour/PictureObj/00073106.JPG (No such file or directory)
```

so where has issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` works for decoding local files only. When you're dealing with a remote address you should download the image using an image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and pass the decoded bitmap to notification builder object. Here is a simple example to download image as bitmap using a blocking method:

```
private Bitmap getLargeIcon(Context context, String picturePath) {
    if (picturePath != null) {
        try {
            return Glide.with(context)
                    .as(Bitmap.class)
                    .load(picturePath)
                    .get(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException ignored) {}
    }
    return null;
}
```

And call the method in your notification function:

```
Bitmap largeIcon = getLargeIcon(this, bigPhoto);
```

**Note:** Since `getLargeIcon` uses a blocking method to download your image, don't forget to call your `sendNotification` function on a worker thread.